# DataContext changes before I can pass parameters

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a control with a dependency property which I want to pass which is a property in a class, and I also want to use an ObservableCollection which part of that class as the datacontext for that control.

```
<mycontrols:News 
   feedStatus="{Binding newsData.newsStore.feedStatus}" 
   DataContext="{Binding newsData.newsStore.news}"
/>
```

The problem here is that the DataContext is used when it evaluates `{Binding newsData.newsStore.feedStatus}` how can I get it to pass feedStatus first and then set the DataContext.

I would use just the single datacontext if silverlight had the ability to back track up the datacontexts parent, but I don't think this is the case.

Could I set datacontext as a nested parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `DataContext` to `DataContext="{Binding newsData.newsStore}` and then bind the `feedStatus` and `news` properties inside your `UserControl`.

Alternatively use multiple dependency properties, instead of the DataContext.

Also, please use .NET naming conventions (PascalCase!). Java style casing makes my eyes cringe.

Comment: my usercontrol can be used for different contexts. in my case `.news` and `.favourites`. sorry I picked up camelCase from C :)

Comment: So design a common interface? The problem here is your API design being utterly terrible, not the actual binding.

Comment: I've been forced to go down the path that work, I would have preferred better techniques but silverlight on phone has led me down blind alleys, as I haven't used mvvmlight or anything.

Comment: I'd be able to use a viewmodel and send parameters but i haven't used that.

Comment: No, it's bloody simple. You create a common interface for the two properties necessary to find, and implement that on your ViewItem/Models. Or you add more dependency properties to your UserControl. It's a architectural issue. Read more up about MVVM. And no workplace can force you to write bad code.

Comment: I hate having to reinvent the wheel because i'm told we don't have time to learn wheel just for this project.

Comment: I'd very much prefer to spend 1 week learning at the beginning of a project than 2 weeks of hair pulling at the end of a project.